# Get jscolor to work with many different inputs

Tags: javascript, php, jscolor

I am using jscolor and I need it to change the color on 5 different inputs in the same code. The problem I am having it, when I change the color on one, it either changes it on all of them or it will just pick the last one.

They have instructions but I don't understand them. Any help would be great.

Here is some of my code:

For Input 1:

```
<input style="width:130px; font-size:14px; padding:5px;" class="jscolor {width:243, height:150, position:'right',
borderColor:'#FFF', insetColor:'#FFF', backgroundColor:'#666', onFineChange:'update(this)'}" id="htcolor" name="htcolor" value="<?php echo $r['htcolor']?>">
```

For Input 2:

```
<input style="width:130px; font-size:14px; padding:5px;" class="jscolor {valueElement:'onecolor', width:243, height:150, position:'right',
borderColor:'#FFF', insetColor:'#FFF', backgroundColor:'#666', onFineChange:'update(this)'}" id="onecolor" name="onecolor" value="<?php echo $r['onecolor']?>">
```

Here is the function code:

```
function update(jscolor) {

$(".htcolor").css("color", jscolor);

$(".onecolor").css("color", jscolor);

 }
```

I really need help with this. Thank you!

I ended up doing it this way and it works...

```
$('#htcolor').on('change', function (e) {
var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
var valueSelected = this.value;
$(".htcolor").css("color", valueSelected);
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that jQuery in use at the last part of your post?  If so, should that not be:

```
$("#htcolor").css("color", jscolor);
$("#onecolor").css("color", jscolor);
```

...to get the element IDs ?

Also, what "instructions" were you viewing ... can you provide a link to the source?

Comment: I'm finding that if I add your two input elements, having no update() function, that the input (background) colors ARE being updated to the selected color from the picker ?   Am I missing something ?

Comment: Ok, it appears that jscolor has some default handling of their own. I'll check a few more things to see if I may have any new information.

Comment: I see your updated comment, but I did reimpose your update() function.  I added an alert and noted that jscolor sends a simple hex string value, (i.e. a5c103) but to use that, you would have to use one of your original functions like this:  $("#htcolor").css("color", "#" + jscolor);   Without prefixing the #, the color does not get applied as expected.